# Adding 3rd-party programs to c:\Program Files with Windows 10 ICD

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, answerfile

I need to add some programs to the c:\Program Files directory for an installation I'm creating using Windows 10 ICD. I did the same thing to a Windows 7 Embedded image using ICE by simply adding the files to the $OEM$\$1 directory in the distribution share folder. Windows ICD doesn't (as far as I can tell) have the same sort of distribution share. Is it possible to add files/programs to an image with ICD? Should I use another program to create my image?

Alternatively, is it possible to insert a batch file into the image customisation?

Thanks